# MATLAB bar graph x-axis step size

Tags: matlab

[A micro electric grid real time data analysis for a complete one day based on number of hours(0-23 hours) x-axis and number of illegal values of voltages on y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTRUs.jpg)

I have a question that how can i make more resolution of x-axis?? like it is coming 0,5,10,15,20... but i want to set step size 1

like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...23.

```
function over_voltage_Red_Phase_bar_graph_per_hour_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global Two_Dimensional_array;

global date_index;

global Restructured_Date_Array;

set(handles.over_voltage_Red_Phase_bar_graph_per_hour,'value',0);

x_axis=Two_Dimensional_array(1,2:25);

y_axis=Two_Dimensional_array(date_index+1,2:25);

figure;

hold all;

xlim([0 23]);

x=x_axis;

b=bar(y_axis,0.4);

xlabel('Hours Detail');

ylabel('Number of Events');

date=Restructured_Date_Array(date_index,1);

legend('Red Phase',date);

grid on;

b(1).FaceColor = 'r';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change axis's steps by using `gca` handle and then changing it's properties. Like here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html

By the way, using this handle you can change a lot of axis parameters the same way. Full list of properties you can get here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html